# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to read and write some non-English characters with python but I am having troubles and do not know why it does not work:

```
a = "hečžo wĐlk" * 10
with open("neki.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(a)

with open("neki.txt", 'r') as f:
    for i in range(4):
        f.seek(i*10)
        print(i)
        print(f.read(10))
```

This is the program output, it works in the first loop pass and then errors:

output:

```
0
hečžo wĐlk
1
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~/githubs/wikiq/diskdic/rank_disk_gen.py in 
      46         f.seek(i*10)
      47         print(i)
----> 48         print(f.read(10))

/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    320         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    321         data = self.buffer + input
--> 322         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    323         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    324         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

If I try to cat neki.txt I get the correct output.

Comment: I have read several questions with a similar title but most of them happened to have a different problem, after several of these I gave up and asked a question. But you are right this is the one that would solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode is very fun. If you comment out the `f.seek` line, the program runs correctly. So why does it error in the first place? The answer is that UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding, meaning that some characters require multiple bytes to store. If we add a `f.tell` to see what the current position is, like this:

```
a = "hečžo wĐlk" * 10
with open("neki.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(a)

with open("neki.txt", 'r') as f:
    for i in range(4):
        #f.seek(i*10)
        print(i)
        print(f.read(10))
        print("curr pos",f.tell())
```

You can see that the byte offset each iteration is actually 13 instead of 10:

```
0
hečžo wĐlk
curr pos 13
1
hečžo wĐlk
curr pos 26
2
hečžo wĐlk
curr pos 39
3
hečžo wĐlk
curr pos 52
```

Your "10 char" string is actually 13 bytes. What this means is that `f.seek(i*10)` will try to seek to byte 10, which happens to be in the middle of a multi-byte char. This will cause the error that you have described.